# Reading a structured file

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, io, iostream

I wrote this short program to read `Order`s from a txt file:

```
struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Date& d)
{
    int dd, m, y;
    char slash1, slash2;
    is >> dd >> slash1 >> m >> slash2 >> y;
    d.day = dd;
    d.month = m;
    d.year = y;
    return is;
}

class Purchase
{
public:
    string product_name;
    double unit_price;
    int count;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Purchase& p)
{
    string pd;
    double price;
    int cnt;
    is >> pd >> price >> cnt;
    if (!is)
    {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    p.product_name = pd;
    p.unit_price = price;
    p.count = cnt;
    return is;
}

struct Address
{
    string add;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Address& a)
{
    string s;
    string aa;
    while (true)
    {
        is >> aa;
        s = s + aa + ' ';
        if (s[s.length() - 2] == '.')break;
    }
    a.add = s;
    return is;
}


class Order
{
public:
    string name;
    Address address;
    Date dt;
    vector<Purchase>purch;
};


istream& operator>>(istream& is, Order& o)
{

    string nm;
    Address aa;
    Date dd;

    is >> nm>> aa >> dd;
    if (!is)
    {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    o.name = nm;
    o.address.add = aa.add;
    o.dt.day = dd.day;
    o.dt.month = dd.month;
    o.dt.year = dd.year;

    for (Purchase pp; is >> pp;)
    {
        o.purch.push_back(pp);
    }
    return is;
}
```

The format of the text file is as follows:

```
John
3, Apple Street, Lagos.
11/3/2018
Soap    100 2
Cream   250 1
Cheese  50  6

Matthew
10, Orange Street, Milan.   
10/1/2018   
Tissue  50  2
Cookies 10  5
Shirts  500 2
Pen 35  1
```

When testing this program in the `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter input file name: ";
    string input_file;
    cin >> input_file;
    ifstream ifs{ input_file };

    vector<Order>ord;

    while (true)
    {
        Order g;
        if (!ifs)break;
        ifs >> g;
        ord.push_back(g);
    }

    cout << ord[0].name << endl;
    cout << ord[0].address.add << endl;
    cout << ord[0].dt.year << endl;
    cout << ord[0].purch[0].count << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

I found at that that it only reads the first instance of `Order` into the `ord` vector. The ifstream `ifs` fails at second attenpt to read a new `Order` and breaks out. So in the example file above, i'm only able to successfully read John's order. Now i'm stuck and I need help. Thanks.

Comment: you're printing just one order (i.e `ord[0]`)

Comment: @codekaizer I just left it that way cos that's the only subscript that works... It says vector subscript out of range when I print `ord[1]`

Comment: `for (Purchase pp; is >> pp;)` loop won't terminate until it consumes the whole file.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I also tried this loop for reading in `Purchase` :  `while (true)
 {
  Purchase pp;
  if (!(is >> pp))break;
  o.purch.push_back(pp);

 }`

Comment: `(is >> pp)` will only ever become `false` (in boolean context) on `eof`, since you have it explicitly clear `failbit` before returning. No shuffling around of the check will change this fact.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please can you guide me on the proper way to leave the Purchase loop without reaching end of file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `for (Purchase pp; is >> pp;)` with

```
int i = 0;
for (Purchase pp; is >> pp && i++ < 3;)
```

You can see that the code runs *kind of* fine.

However, this creates the problem of variable purchase size. What should be the size of the loop constant?
I'd recommend using a **sentinel**, like '1' in your data at the end of each object. Then you can modify the loop to:

`for (Purchase pp; is.peek() != 1 && is >> pp;)`

Also, don't forget after the loop to kill the next character (it will be '1')

`char c; is >> c;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GillBates for the sentinel idea and @IgorTandetnik for exposing the faulty part in my code. I was able to rectify the issue by using integer indexes at the beginning of each order and then adding is.clear() at the end of the operator>>Order function.